# How to delete all contents of a directory without deleting the directory

Tags: php

I have a directory on my server that I need to clear out using PHP. I need to delete all files and folders inside this directory, however, I do not want to delete the main directory itself. Everything I have read, examples I have found, they all seem to delete everything inside the directory given but then after it also deletes the given directory. One function I tried is below, but again it also deletes the main directory and I can't have that.

```
<?php
function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this `rmdir($dir);` on the last part of your function.

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
      $objects = scandir($dir);
      foreach ($objects as $object) {
        if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
          if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
             rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
          else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
        }
      }
      reset($objects);
    // rmdir($dir); => this line deletes the directory you specified after its content has been deleted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your existing code *rmdir($dir);*, with this line your are also removing the parent directory that you passed on your function parameter. I've also added what code snippet I usually use for deleting contents from directory.

```
function remove_directory($str) {
 //It it's a file.
 if (is_file($str)) {
     //Attempt to delete it.
     return unlink($str);
 }
 //If it's a directory.
 elseif (is_dir($str)) {
    //Get a list of the files in this directory.
    $scan = glob(rtrim($str,'/').'/*');
    //Loop through the list of files.
    foreach($scan as $index=>$path) {
        //Call our recursive function.
        remove_directory($path);
    }
    //Remove the directory itself.
    return @rmdir($str);
  }
 }

//call our function
 $dir='directory_name';
 remove_directory($dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of the code I posted before also deleted subdirectories, so removing the last rmdir in the code would stop it from doing that. However, I was able to make changes to the code that works. This code will delete all contents inside the given directory including files and folders without deleting the given directory.

```
function rrmdir($dir, $issub = false) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")
                     rrmdir($dir."/".$object, true);
                else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        if($issub) {
          rmdir($dir);
        }
    }
}
```